# How can I get item label from selectOneMenu @ JSF page

Tags: jsf, text, primefaces, label, selectonemenu

I'm dealing with a wizard in primefaces like this one:

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/wizard.jsf

I would like to get the raw text from a selectOneMenu (from one of the tabs) and show it in the confirmation tab.

My selectOneMenu looks like this:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="vinculos"
      value="#{socioAdicional.idVinculo}" required="true"
      label="Vinculo">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{mensajes.combos_empty_txt}" itemValue="#{null}" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{controladorCombos.vinculos}"
                  var="vinculo" itemLabel="#{vinculo.descripcion}"
                  itemValue="#{vinculo.id}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

All the values are obtained from a webservice and can't be stored in an map attribute, cause we are using other buffering strategies...

I've tried so far to print that text (on a different tab) like this:

```
<b>Vinculo: </b><h:outputText value="#{p:component('vinculos').getSelectedValue()}"/>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You are already saving value to your variable idVinculo so just retrieve from it.

Comment: Nope, that's the id, I need the text value...

Comment: Which text value ? itemLabel ?

Comment: That's right, itemLabel, not itemValue

Answer (score 2):

*Either* use a `Map<ItemId, Item>` as available items, so that you can get the whole `Item` at hands based on the selected item ID:

```
private Long selectedItemId;
private Map<Long, Item> availableItems;
```

```html
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.selectedItemId}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.availableItems.values()}" var="item"
        itemValue="#{item.id}" itemLabel="#{item.description}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
...
<b>Selected item:</b> #{bean.availableItems[bean.selectedItemId].description}.
```

*Or* use whole `Item` instead of `Id` as selected item, with a converter, so that you immediately already have the whole `Item` at hands:

```
private Item selectedItem;
private List<Item> availableItems;
```

```html
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.selectedItem}" converter="itemConverter">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.availableItems}" var="item"
        itemValue="#{item}" itemLabel="#{item.description}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
...
<b>Selected item:</b> #{bean.selectedItem.description}.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I can't hold all available items on a map, since there are lots and lots of selectOneMenu widgets and all values are obtained from a webservice (those values may change between two requests)

Comment: To save yourself from converter pain, you may find OmniFaces `SelectItemsConverter` helpful. http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/SelectItemsConverter

Comment: Refer post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141716/jsf-selectitems-how-to-get-both-label-and-value/23167788#23167788, using, List <SelectItem>: may help!