# Get string behind binding object

Tags: jsf

I have the following JSF construct:

```
    <c:set var="myVar" value="#{myBean.getMyMap()}" scope="request" />
    <h:form>
    <p>
        <h:outputText value="Output1: " />
        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{myMappingsBean.data.attribute1}" binding="#{input1}" required="true">
            <f:selectItems var="entry" value="#{myVar}"/>
            <p:ajax update="myDropdown"/>
        </h:selectOneMenu>
    </p>
    <p>
        <h:outputText value="Output2: " />
        <h:selectOneMenu id="myDropdown" value="#{myMappingsBean.data.attribute2}" binding="#{input2}" required="true" converter="javax.faces.Double">
            <f:selectItems var="entry" value="#{myVar.get(input1.value)}"/>
        </h:selectOneMenu>
    </p>
    </h:form>
```

Behind myVar is a map defined like that: `Map<String, Collection<Double>>`

The first dropdown menu shows a list of all the keys of that map (like desired), but the value behind that is the collection of values.
Here the HTML output of one option of that dropdown:

```
<option value="[1.0, 2.0]">SomeString</option>
```

My second dropdown should list the collection of double values stored in the map behind the key, that is selected by the first menu.
**The problem now is**, when I use `value="#{myVar.get(input1.value)}"` the value I get from `.value` is the collection and not the string/key of the map. So I never get the desired result.
How can I get the string/key behind the binded object `input1`? Is there something like `input1.name` or `.toString`? Is somewhere a documentary for this?

Comment: Please attache the bean sources. Access bean fields trough properties (getter/setter methods) in EL expressions : `... value="#{myBean.myMap}"`

Comment: There is no attribute myMap in the bean. There is only the method getMyMap() that returns the said map. It's also not going to be changed by the page, so I guess no setter is needed.
All the other setter and getter of `.data` just set or return the variable.
My problem lies within the object `input1`. With `.value` I get the value, but I also need the string that is hopefully also stored there.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it by applying the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141716/how-to-get-both-label-and-value-from-fselectitems).
The first drop down has to be edited to the following:

```
    <p>
        <h:outputText value="Output1: " />
        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{myMappingsBean.data.attribute1}" binding="#{input1}" required="true">
            <f:selectItems var="entry" value="#{myVar.entrySet()}" itemValue="#{entry.key}" itemLabel="#{entry.key}"/>
        </h:selectOneMenu>
    </p>
```

As you can see, the entry set is created from the map and from that you use the key as value and label. 
And with that the value behind `input1.value` now is not the collection of doubles but the key of the map.